# C++ template function with pointer arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I have this code

```
template <class N>
inline N swap(N a, N b) {
    int c = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = c;
}
```

with this function I get this error: `error: 'N' does not name a type
Error compiling.`

This is my normal function.

```
inline void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int c = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = c;
}
```

My problem is that I need to use this function with unsigned and normal ints.
Is it possible to do this with templates.

Comment: Why not use `std::swap`?

Comment: Because I'm using arduino and I would like to know how it works.

Comment: And what if the template type `T` is not an integer? Or the arguments not pointers?

Comment: How do hou call this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
template<typename T>
inline void swap(T* a, T* b) // Use T* if you're expecting pointers
       ^^^^ // Notice the return type
{
    T c = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = c;
}
```

Comment: The `int` looks out of place.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes, I copied it from their implementation... I'll fix it

Comment: It was fault by Arduino IDE, I have to declare `template<typename T> inline void swap(T *a, T *b);` before the function. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change declaration of the pointer from `int c` to `N* c` because it may take another data type as parameter , in addition to that you can't put a value of a pointer in a normal variable .